# How to add the iOS “Open In…” feature to my navigation app

Tags: ios, dictionary, navigation

I have a navigation app. I would like to pop up all navigation apps when user press, address, let the user can press my app and pass the latitude and longitude to my app. I know when I click a file on mail app, it will pop “Open in" menu and suggest me apps.

I check the https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html

I have not found the address of file type.

So, how can I do? I already use URL scheme to achieve A app call B app,

But this time I would like to use “Open in” menu.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking out [Localide](https://github.com/davoda/Localide). It helps you open Google Maps, Waze, Apple Maps, Transit App, Citymapper, and Navigon very easily. You'll need to have a coordinate though which you should have if it's a navigation app!